# my servlet code is throwing exception. In database one column is check_in of Date type and other is for rooms(10 fixed per date) which is of int type

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, prepared-statement

My database consists of two columns one is `Date` type and another is of `int` type. My jsp code is booking.jsp (not included here) and servlet file is booking.java as shown below. But I click on check availability it is showing exception For input string: "date".

**booking.java**

```
package com.dit.project;    
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class booking extends HttpServlet {
     Connection con;
PreparedStatement pst,pst1;
ResultSet rs;
String msg;


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        con=DBService.getConnection();
        pst=con.prepareStatement("select * from database where check_in=? and rooms=?");
        int check_in=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("check_in"));
        int rooms=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rooms"));

        pst.setInt(1,check_in);
        pst.setInt(2, rooms);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next())
        {
            int left=10-(rs.getInt(2));
            if(rooms>10 || rooms>left)
            {
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("booking.jsp");
                msg="<font color=red>cann't book more rooms</font>";
                request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
                rd.forward(request, response);

            }
            else{
                if(rooms==0){
                     RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("booking.jsp");
                msg="<font color=red>Sorry! ther are no rooms left</font>";
                request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
                rd.forward(request, response);
                }
                else{
                    pst1=con.prepareStatement("update database set rooms=left where check_in=rs.getInt(1)");
                    pst1.setInt(1,check_in);
                    pst1.setInt(2, rooms);
                    int i=pst1.executeUpdate();
                    if(i>0){
                          RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("booking.jsp");
                msg="<font color=red>bookings done of"+rooms+"</font>";
                request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
                rd.forward(request, response);

                    }
                }
            }

        }


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        out.close();
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(booking.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(booking.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>

}
```

Comment: Please change your question title to summarize your question/problem, not your program.

Comment: Sir,i have changed it.please tell me where i am going wrong in this programme?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know JSP.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are providing the wrong data type in the prepared statement for `check_in`.

When you do,

`int check_in=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("check_in"));`

You are essentially converting value of `check_in` parameter which is `String` to an `int`. It should be converted to `Date` type, `java.sql.Date` type to be precised. Use the following code to set Date type value in prepared statement,

```
pst.setDate(1,java.sql.Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("check_in")));
```

Or as the existing approach that you have, you can do the following,

```
java.sql.Date check_in = java.sql.Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("check_in"));
```

Then do,

```
pst.setDate(1,check_in);
```

Comment: sir,rooms and check_in both are now int type I have changed it but it is still showing null exception?

Comment: @ReenaKandari null pointer at which line in your code? Would you try posting the stack trace? Or let me know at which line it is happening?

Comment: Yes sir I have traced it.It appears at line ' pst=con.prepareStatement("select * from database where check_in=? and rooms=?")'

Comment: If that is the case then the problem should be with, `con=DBService.getConnection();` check that `DBService` class and `getConnection()` method as well. I feel `con` is coming as null after the `con=DBService.getConnection();` call.

Comment: sir,I have checked it but there seems everything  right here.